# Pandas - methods for combining similar column values into a larger supergroup

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, levenshtein-distance

So I have a large dataset, and one of the columns contains values gathered from freetext (so some words are misspelled or similarly spelled). For example:

```
Diagnosis
----------
headache
headache
headche
UTI
cough
cough
cough
UTIs
UTI
coughs
UTI
...
```

I'm looking for ways to go through this data and 'combine' things. For the most part, the majority of entries are spelled correctly for the word they're trying to spell (for example, 'cough'). What I'm looking for is, for example, 'coughs' to be mapped to 'cough' because its Levenschtein distance is small, and 'cough' occurs more times than 'coughs' does. In doing this, the above column would be mapped to:

```
Diagnosis
----------
headache
headache
headache
UTI
cough
cough
cough
UTI
UTI
cough
UTI
...
```

So that there are now only three unique values. Also, it's important to note that I have thousands of rows with misspellings and extra characters so mapping by hand isn't really an option here. I've looked at score_sort using the fuzzy wuzzy package, but it takes far too long and doesn't seem to work for my particular problem.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: have you tries finding the similar text using only unique values?

Comment: @BabakFiFoo Could you expand on this please?

Comment: @Scroks You have multiple values in your column that have exactly the same string. Matching thousands of rows with fuzzy wuzzy is computationally intensive. But if you try to get all unique values and construct the replacement, then you can fix the issue with much less processing time. I will write my answer. See if it solves your isseu. If not just let me know.

Comment: your answer is ready :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need these libraries:

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from itertools import combinations
import networkx as nx
```

Let us assume that `Diagnosis` is your column series:

```
Diagnosis = pd.Series(["headache","headache","headche","UTI",
"cough","cough","cough","UTIs","UTI","coughs","UTI"])
```

Lets do some string matching:

```
Diagnosis_unique = Diagnosis.unique()
matches = pd.DataFrame(combinations(Diagnosis_unique,2))
matches['score'] = matches.apply(lambda x: fuzz.WRatio(x[0],x[1]), axis=1)
```

Here is the `matches` data frame :

```
|    | 0        | 1       |   score |
|---:|:---------|:--------|--------:|
|  0 | headache | headche |      93 |
|  1 | headache | UTI     |       0 |
|  2 | headache | cough   |      45 |
|  3 | headache | UTIs    |       0 |
|  4 | headache | coughs  |      14 |
|  5 | headche  | UTI     |       0 |
|  6 | headche  | cough   |      17 |
|  7 | headche  | UTIs    |       0 |
|  8 | headche  | coughs  |      15 |
|  9 | UTI      | cough   |      30 |
| 10 | UTI      | UTIs    |      86 |
| 11 | UTI      | coughs  |      30 |
| 12 | cough    | UTIs    |      22 |
| 13 | cough    | coughs  |      91 |
| 14 | UTIs     | coughs  |      45 |
```

Now, let us drop the rows that do not match. I used a score of 80. you can use your preferred score:

```
matches = matches[matches['score']>=80]
```

Now that we have the matches, we need to connect similar names. In your example, there is only one type of typo in each work. However, there might be more. So we need to ask graph theory for help:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(matches,0,1)

connected_names=pd.DataFrame()
for cluster in nx.connected_components(G):
    if len(cluster) != 1:
        connected_names = connected_names.append([list(cluster)])
```

Now we have a graph with clusters of nodes that are similar. We need to convert it to a dictionary for replacing our original data:

```
connected_names = connected_names\
    .reset_index(drop=True)\
        .melt(id_vars=0)\
            .drop('variable', axis=1)\
                .dropna()\
                    .reset_index(drop=True)\
                        .set_index('value')

names_dict = connected_names.to_dict()[0]
```

Here is the `names_dict`:

```
{'headache': 'headche', 'UTIs': 'UTI', 'cough': 'coughs'}
```

The downside of this method is that you cannot decide what value is the correct spelling. However, you can fix this manually later.

Now lets replace the original series:

```
Diagnosis = Diagnosis.replace(names_dict)
```

And Voila!

```
|    | 0       |
|---:|:--------|
|  0 | headche |
|  1 | headche |
|  2 | headche |
|  3 | UTI     |
|  4 | coughs  |
|  5 | coughs  |
|  6 | coughs  |
|  7 | UTI     |
|  8 | UTI     |
|  9 | coughs  |
| 10 | UTI     |
```

What you can do in the end is constructing your own correct dictionary to correct unified values:

```
manual_correction = {"headche":"headache"}
Diagnosis = Diagnosis.replace(manual_correction)
```

result:

```
|    | 0        |
|---:|:---------|
|  0 | headache |
|  1 | headache |
|  2 | headache |
|  3 | UTI      |
|  4 | coughs   |
|  5 | coughs   |
|  6 | coughs   |
|  7 | UTI      |
|  8 | UTI      |
|  9 | coughs   |
| 10 | UTI      |
```