# Replace an item in a column with a similar item from that column that has repeated the most

Tags: python, pandas, string, nlp, cosine-similarity

I have a list of job titles, the no of unique job titles are around 24,000. Most of the job titles are very similar.

```
For example:

Software Developer, Software engineer, software engineering, software engineer 2, senior software engineer, junior software engineer,....
```

I want to find the most similar titles and replace all the the similar titles with the most repeated title to reduce the uniqueness in the column.

For example, in the screenshots, all the variations of aadhar card supervisor will be replaced with aadhar supervisor since it has been repeated most often. all variants of Software engineering jobs will be replaced with software engineer title since it has been repeated very often, and so on...

Please suggest solutions and approaches to achieve this desired result.

Sample Job titles for your reference is here in this repository:
https://github.com/skwolvie/jobprofile_sample

I have also tabulated the similarity scores of a title with every other title in the sample job title dataset. each title is associated with a value_counts score.

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Check this answer for a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69107603/7705000

Comment: Hi Joao, thanks for the above reference, I also edited this question with a sample dataset link. Hopefully this will be useful for someone in future. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Joao, the solution you gave is good, but it is infeasible because of the no of possible combinations in my dataset is 2.8 Billion. Is there any other possible but faster solutions?

Comment: In the end, you will have to compare each word against the others to have a measure of similarity, so there will be a computational burden to calculate the distances. However, I imagine that you don't have 2.8 Billion *unique* job titles. If this is the case, you have to figure out a way to do the calculations between each pair of unique titles only once and cache the results.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another try:

There are 5 steps in this solution:

1. Use `pd.Series.value_counts().reset_index()` to get only unique titles in descending order of frequency.
2. Calculate the distances between these unique `titles` using the Levenshtein distance measure
3. Find the indices of the words most close to each word using a `threshold` in the Levenshtein distances
4. Consolidate the nodes of duplicates to avoid repetition (i.e., if ids 1, 2, and 5 are duplicates, we want only one entry for them and not [1, 2, 5], [2, 1, 5], and [5, 1, 2]).
5. Finally, we consolidate the information into the `df.title.value_counts()` series and in a dictionary to replace in the original DataFrame.

Code based on the `csv` file you shared earlier:

```py
# Load required libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import Levenshtein
from collections import defaultdict
```

STEP1: Load data (it is already in the value_counts() desired format)

```py
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/skwolvie/jobprofile_sample/main/sample_jobprofiles.csv", 
        index_col=False)
df.columns = ['title', "frequency"]
```

STEP2: Calculate the distances

```py
def levenshtein_matrix(titles):
    """
    Fill a matrix with the Levenshtein ratio between each word in a list
    of words with each other.

    Since Levenshtein.ratio(w1, w2) == Levenshtein.ratio(w2, w1), we can
    sequentially decrease the lenght of the inner loop in order to calculate
    the Levenshtein ratio distance only once
    """
    size = len(titles)
    final = np.zeros((size, size))
    for i, w1 in enumerate(titles):
        for j, w2 in enumerate(titles[i:], i):
            lev = Levenshtein.ratio(w1, w2)
            final[i, j] = lev
            final[j, i] = lev

    return final

titles = df.title

lev_matrix = levenshtein_matrix(titles) # 30 seconds to run in my machine with 7k+ items
```

STEP3: Loop through each row of the `lev_matrix` to find the ids of similar entries

```py
# Create function
def get_similar_nodes(distance_matrix, threshold=.9):
    """
    Takes a matrix of distances and returns a generator with the entries
    that have a distance measure higher than threshold for each row
    in the matrix.
    """
        
    for i in lev_matrix:
        yield np.where(i > threshold)[0].tolist()

similar_nodes = get_similar_nodes(lev_matrix)
```

STEP4: Consolidate all the lists that share at least one item in a single list

```py
def connected_components(lists):
    """
    This function yields a generator with all connected lists inside the given
    list of lists.
    """
    neighbors = defaultdict(set)
    seen = set()
    for each in lists:
        for item in each:
            neighbors[item].update(each)
    def component(node, neighbors=neighbors, seen=seen, see=seen.add):
        nodes = set([node])
        next_node = nodes.pop
        while nodes:
            node = next_node()
            see(node)
            nodes |= neighbors[node] - seen
            yield node
    for node in neighbors:
        if node not in seen:
            yield sorted(component(node))

connected_nodes = list(connected_components(similar_nodes))
```

For updating the values, you create a dictionary mapping all names to the most common name in their group and pass it to the DataFrame.

Note that using `nodes[0]` as the most common title in the node works because the DataFrame is ordered by descending frequency since we created it using `.value_counts()`.

```py
# Copy the DataFrame for comparison
df_test = df.copy()

dict_most_popular_names = {}
for nodes in connected_nodes:
    dict_most_popular_names |= {key: titles[nodes[0]] for key in titles[nodes]}

# Check the dictionary
titles[connected_nodes[0]][:3]
# >>> 0         'software engineer'
# >>> 20     'software qa engineer'
# >>> 23     'software engineer ii'
# >>> Name: title, dtype: object

dict_most_popular_names["software engineer qa"]
# >>> 'software engineer'
dict_most_popular_names["software engineer"]
# >>> 'software engineer'
dict_most_popular_names["software engineer ii"]
# >>> 'software engineer'

# Update the dataframe
df_test["clean_title"] = [dict_most_popular_names[x] for x in titles]
```

You can use the `dict_most_popular_names` to replace in your original dataframe as well.

For me, run this whole script takes 30 seconds, which is pretty much the time spent calculating the Levenshtein distances. If you need to optimize further, there is where you need to check.